# SSRS Matrix add Percentage column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

I have a matrix report with the following rows and columns names:
Row group: agecategory
column group: columngroup1
data calculated: count(clientID)

Here is an example of a matrix graphic with data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sak8.jpg)

I have created the following expression in order to calculate the percentage of each line:

=count(Fields!iMemberID.Value, "columngroup1")/Count(Fields!iMemberID.Value, "agecategory")

but it gives me expression value error. How can I add a percentage column to the matrix? PLease, I really appreciate it.

Thank you,
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

If what you have shown in the image is your entire report, then you don't need to use a matrix, a standard tablix will be better. You can change this by removing the column groups.

Then you can add a new new column and use an expression similar to what you had already tried. The expression needs to be the count within rowgroup divided by the count within the dataset, so if you dataset is called `dsMyData` then the expression would look like this.

```
=count(Fields!iMemberID.Value, "agecategory")/Count(Fields!iMemberID.Value, "dsMyData")
```